# Camera Follow - Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can't get this line to work without error, it needs a temp variable. Without it the camera is flat on the ground

```
transform.position.y = currentHeight;
```

error CS1612: Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

Part of the code is not mine, just trying to convert from java script to c-sharp and implement in my current camera script

```
 // Calculate the current rotation angles
 var wantedRotationAngle = target.eulerAngles.y;
 var wantedHeight = target.position.y + height;
 var currentRotationAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
 var currentHeight = transform.position.y;
 // Damp the rotation around the y-axis
 currentRotationAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle (currentRotationAngle, wantedRotationAngle, rotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);
 // Damp the height

 currentHeight = Mathf.Lerp (currentHeight, wantedHeight, heightDamping * Time.deltaTime);
 // Convert the angle into a rotation

 var currentRotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, currentRotationAngle, 0);
 // Set the position of the camera on the x-z plane to:
 // distance meters behind the target
 transform.position = target.position;
 transform.position -= currentRotation * Vector3.forward * distance;
 // Set the height of the camera

 transform.position.y = currentHeight;

 // Always look at the target
 transform.LookAt (target);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe you can set the seperate axis' of the vector like that, one way you'd do it is

```
// Calculate the current rotation angles
var wantedRotationAngle = target.eulerAngles.y;
var wantedHeight = target.position.y + height;
var currentRotationAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
var currentHeight = transform.position.y;
// Damp the rotation around the y-axis
currentRotationAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle (currentRotationAngle, wantedRotationAngle, rotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);
// Damp the height

currentHeight = Mathf.Lerp (currentHeight, wantedHeight, heightDamping * Time.deltaTime);
// Convert the angle into a rotation

var currentRotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, currentRotationAngle, 0);
// Set the position of the camera on the x-z plane to:
// distance meters behind the target
transform.position = target.position;
transform.position -= currentRotation * Vector3.forward * distance;
// Set the height of the camera

Vector3 temp = transform.position; //Get the current vector the transform is at
temp.y = currentHeight; //assign the new value to the Y axis
transform.position = temp; //replace the existing vector with the new one we just modified.

// Always look at the target
transform.LookAt (target);
```

so we are replacing your `transform.position.y = currentHeight;` line with

```
Vector3 temp = transform.position; //Get the current vector the transform is at
temp.y = currentHeight; //assign the new value to the Y axis
transform.position = temp; //replace the existing vector with the new one we just modified.
```

This is simply due to the way C# is handling structs and properties, to my belief.

Comment: That's going to result in the same problem, surely? That `y` cannot be modified? I think it needs to be assigned a new object: `transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, currentHeight, transform.position.z);`

Comment: It's been a while since i've used unity but i *believe* this does infact work. Will need @Alex_TNT to confirm.

Comment: Cool, thought I'd check :)

Comment: This confusion is because `Vector3` is a mutable struct. `transform.position` gets a copy of the struct, so you have to take the copy, manipulate it, and set `transform.position` again. Unity did this for performance reasons, although it can be extremely confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify transform.position x and y directly, instead of that you should create a Vector3 variable with desired values and then assign your transform.position to it. For example:

```
 Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(0, currentHeight, 0);
 transform.position = newPosition;
```